# Why does vscode delete golang source on save

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

why can't save these line of code in vscode with golang extension

```
package app

import (
  "fmt"
)

//this is just func
func TestingHello(){
  fmt.Println("Hissssss")
}
```

only the `package app` stays and remaining part got deleted on save in vscode.

Comment: Does this happens to every golang file? Try saving to another path and/or another filename?

Comment: to me happens on wrong detected not used import. so i have for free a build fail thanks to this smart auto delete code on saving. :)

Answer (score 82):

config both editor.formatOnSave and  editor.codeActionsOnSave in the settings.json:

```
"[go]": {

        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": false
        },
    },
    "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
```

Comment: This is a better solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this one also worked for me. Thanks !!

Comment: I love this answer so much I want to marry it.

Comment: wonder, why not just highlight the problem instead of removing it and making me wonder and wander for answers :D

Comment: If anyone is wondering where to find the settings.json file, it's in your project folder under  .vscode folder. @LoremIpsum how can someone do this globally?

Comment: Is there a way to configure it so it still formats the code but doesn't delete anything?  I like the formatting but deleting stuff is just sacrilege

Answer (score 51):

Basically, your formatOnSave is on for go which is causing this problem.

To disable it, go to your Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), type in "configure language specific settings", and look for Go.

You should now see a json file where you can add the following setting to it:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

This is how the json file looks like if you just have on setting modified for go:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "[go]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankss mate you save my time

Comment: This answer does not work for me. see the answer by LoremIpsum or this comment on the issue here https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1231#issuecomment-779738892

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue that was caused by not having the right case on method names.

In the following code `import "fmt"` would disappear.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.println("hello world")
}
```

**Solution** I should be calling `Println` **NOT** `println` ! Note the uppercase `P`. Once changed `goreturns` adds the import instead of removing it.

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure this out and didn't realise it was a capital P. Thanks!

Comment: @seanleroy Really glad it helped somebody :)

Comment: I had this exact problem working with golang for the first time.

Answer (score 10):

By default Format Tool is set to "goreturns" in settings.json, change it to "fmt":

```
{
    "go.formatTool": "gofmt"
}
```

Now you can comment the imports:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    // "reflect"
    // "math/rand"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried all the go format tools available in vscode. goImports and goreturns "fixed" my code (it won't compile anymore), while gofmt and goformat don't. Switched to gofmt for now.

Answer (score 9):

Ctrl+Shift+P   --> Configure Language Specific Settings

```
       "editor.insertSpaces": false,
        "editor.formatOnSave": **false,**
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": **false**
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

That seems strange.
I can understand the import disappearing (as in [issue 748](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/748)) because of [`goreturns` (`github.com/sqs/goreturns`)](https://github.com/sqs/goreturns) removing unused import. But that shouldn't apply in your case.

But if almost everything disappears, that means the file fails to be saved, and revert to its original content.
Maybe another process is keeping an handle on that file, preventing the save operation to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

```
"[go]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": "never"
        },
    },
    "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
```

In VS-Code-Version: 1.80.0 or higher `false` in "source.organizeImports" will be deprecated. So, use instead `"never"`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happening is because of what you imported, you didn't use it in the program, so Golang deletes unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple answer that I found:

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
    )
    
    func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
    }
    `
```

Make sure `P` is capital of `Println` , I spent hours to find out this error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the changes did not take effect until I re-loaded the window.

For every change, run

1. Cmd + Shift + P
2. `>Developer: Reload Window`

Answer (score -1):

On VScode just press (CTRL + SHIFT + P ).

Then, Click on "Configure language-specific settings"
and select GO lang.

Just paste code

```
"[go]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like these values should be set to `false`...

Answer (score -1):

Now its

```
{
    "source.organizeImports": "never"
}
```