# Why vscode removes golang script when doing save

Tags: json, go, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble here when I want to save my golang project, where when I want to import "fmt" then I save the "fmt" script it disappears. then how do i fix it

setting.json (vscode) :

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor" : "newUntitledFile",
    "workbench.iconTheme" : "vscode-icons",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "editor.suggestSelection" : "first",
    "vsintelllicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection":"automatically",
    "workbench.colorTheme":"Material Theme Ocean",
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage":"true"
}
```

Comment: Sounds like unused import removal. Unused imports are removed because the language prohibits them and trying to compile a program with an unused import will fail with an error. You should either use the imported package or not import it at all.

Comment: A similar answer to this question can be found here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124565/why-does-vscode-delete-golang-source-on-save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't need to manually add imports. Write `fmt.Println(1)` and see if it keeps it.